# How to insert primary key from one table as a foreign key into secondary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am creating a sample database with two tables `submissions` and `submittedItems`. I am populating this table with sample data and I wanted to know how to populate the second table with the primary key from the first table.

The script I have  works fine for what I am testing however I am currently inserting the foreign key by simply mirroring the count. Since this is a new table it works fine as both start with the same number. Where my question is what if the table already had data within it, How would I go about retrieving the PK of the last record entered into the submissions table?  I know when using Identity I could use `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to get the last identity entered but not sure of the proper select statement to use for anything else. OR am I misunderstanding the use of `Scope_Identity()` and it does retrieve whatever the last PK/Identity that was entered? As you can see I am no expert at sql so if there is a better approach I would welcome any suggestions.

Thanks in advance,

```
use SampleRecords
GO
--create two test tables
CREATE TABLE submissions
(submission_id int Identity(1,1) primary key not null,
submissionName varchar(150),
dateSubmitted datetime)

CREATE TABLE submissionItems
(submissionitems_id int identity(1,1) primary key,
fk_submission_id int  not null,
item varchar(150),
CONSTRAINT fk_submission_id foreign key (fk_submission_id) references submissions (submission_id))

--populate tables with sample data
DECLARE @totalRecords int 
SET @totalRecords = 0
DECLARE @currentKey int

WHILE @totalRecords < 500
BEGIN

SET @totalRecords = @totalRecords + 1
INSERT INTO dbo.submissions (submissionName, dateSubmitted)
VALUES
('submission record ' + cast(@totalRecords AS varchar(3)), SYSDATETIME())

INSERT INTO dbo.submissionItems (fk_submission_id, item)
VALUES
(@totalRecords, 'a new record item for submission '+ cast(@totalRecords AS varchar(3)))

-- I tried using scope_identity as follows but could not get the syntax correct
-- ('submission record ' + cast(Select Scope_Identity() AS varchar(3)), SYSDATETIME())

END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just use the ScopeIdentity...

```
--populate tables with sample data
DECLARE @totalRecords int 
SET @totalRecords = 0
DECLARE @currentKey int

WHILE @totalRecords < 500
BEGIN
    SET @totalRecords = @totalRecords + 1

    INSERT INTO dbo.submissions (submissionName, dateSubmitted)
        VALUES ('submission record ' + cast(@totalRecords AS varchar(3)), SYSDATETIME())

    Set @currentKey = Scope_Identity()

    INSERT INTO dbo.submissionItems (fk_submission_id, item)
        VALUES (@currentKey, 'a new record item for submission '+ cast(@totalRecords AS varchar(3)))
END
```